# How do I select unnamed node in HTML or XML using XPath?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I try to access the text inside the `<dl>` environment following the `<p>` environment with the text "Bedeutungen:" inside. I try to specify an XPath to select this specific `<dl>` node.

```
<p><span style="visibility:hidden" id="Bedeutungen"><span id="Anker:Bedeutungen"></span></span></p><p style="margin-bottom:-0.5em; font-weight:bold;" title="Sinn und Bezeichnetes (Semantik)">Bedeutungen:</p>
<dl><dd>[1] roh <a href="/wiki/essbar" title="essbar">essbare</a>, meist saftige Früchte, die von Bäumen, Sträuchern und mehrjährigen Stauden stammen, mit überwiegend süßlichem oder säuerlichem, "fruchtigem" Geschmack</dd></dl>
```

This is an excerpt from the German wiktionary entry for Obst "fruit" ([a link](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Obst)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the targeted element based upon the label that precedes it:

This XPath,

```
string(//dl[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p][normalize-space()='Bedeutungen:']])
```

will return the string value of the `dl` element with an immediately preceding sibling `p` element with a space-normalized string value equal to `'Bedeutungen:'`:

```
[1] roh essbare, meist saftige Früchte, die von Bäumen, Sträuchern und mehrjährigen Stauden stammen, mit überwiegend süßlichem oder säuerlichem, "fruchtigem" Geschmack
```